# Cannot create UDF function on Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I run my pyspark locally and have been unable to create an UDF

I've tried to make a test UDF. even that failed with the same error.

here's a test UDF that i've made, it just returned the same string input

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def test_udf(string):
    return string

F.udf(lambda x: test_udf(x), StringType())
```

here's the error i got:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.get.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.sql.execution.pythonUDF.arrow.enabled
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.noSuchElementExceptionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1678)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.$anonfun$getConfString$3(SQLConf.scala:4577)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getConfString(SQLConf.scala:4577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.get(RuntimeConfig.scala:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

i have been looking in the internet for the solution but i've found nothing

Comment: Code works fine for me on python 3.11.0,spark version 3.4.1,Using Scala version 2.12.17, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.7

Comment: Just do `my_udf = F.udf(test_udf, StringType())`

Comment: updating the spark and java version fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by installing PyArrow